# How to add css class to transcluded ng-repeat content in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I simplify my problem as following: I want to make a `myDirective` directive so that:

Developer input:

```
<my-directive>
    <label ng-repeat="opt in [1,2]">
       <input type="radio" name="radio" id="opt" value="opt" ng-model="radioModel.name"> Radio {{opt}}
    </label>
</my-directive>
```

Expected html output:

```
<my-directive>
    <label class="myClass">
       <input type="radio" name="radio" id="opt" value="opt" ng-model="radioModel.name"> Radio {{opt}}
    </label>
    <label class="myClass">
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="opt" value="opt" ng-model="radioModel.name"> Radio {{opt}}
    </label >
</my-directive>
```

My question is how could I dynamically add class "myClass" to each label tag? Here is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnghi223/a716nrns/5/). As you see, currently I'm able to do so because I manually added each label tag one by one, but I want to use ng-repeat instead. Any ideas/inputs are appreciated.

Comment: you should be able to just do this `<label class="myClass" ng-repeat="i in [1,2]">{{i}}</label>`

Comment: @AmanuelBogale. Sorry, no. What I meant was I wanted to dynamically add class "myClass" to each label tag. Your solution works because the css rule is so simple, but image a more complex rule where, say you want each label tag has its own padding, border-radius etc. Also see my updated example.

Comment: Same thing @GreatQuestion . You would just add the border-radius, and all the styling into one class and add it...

Comment: @AmanuelBogale, look, you miss my point. Now if you go to your jsfidle, open dev tool, and hover the label tag, you will see something like this: <label class="ng-scope">1</label>. But what I'd like to have is <label class="ng-scope myClass">1</label>. Because I want "myClass" to apply to each label tag individually.

Comment: Oh now i see what you want @GreatQuestion . Can you wait some time so i edit?

Comment: The only way to attack that problem as i see now is to add element.AddClass('ClassName')... @GreatQuestion

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a ng-class....

**HTML**

```
<my-directive ng-class="{'myClass':true}">
  <label>1</label>
  <label>2</label>
</my-directive>
```

**JS**

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        transclude:true,
        template:"<div></div>",
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs,ctrl,transclude) {
            transclude(scope,function(clone) {

                elm.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**CSS**

```
body {
   background-color: #eef;     
}
.myClass {
    color: red;
}
```

As seen in fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a716nrns/4/).

### EDIT

After understanding your problem, the only way to attack it is to add element.AddClass('className') , In the directive.

```
var app=angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'EA',
        transclude:true,
        template:"<div></div>",
        scope:true,
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs,ctrl) {
                element.AddClass('myClass');
                $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: where does 'element' come from? And I guess you mean addClass?

Comment: Its angular.element @GreatQuestion look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: it seems to me that your edit solution does not work. both element and $compile are undefined. It would be great if you can try that out with jsfiddle. Also take into account that the html should use ng-repeat, so you dont want to manually copy and paste <label> tag in the case there are 1000 of them.

Comment: Btw @GreatQuestion how do you use the console in JSFiddle?

Comment: you just type in console.log('something') in the JavaScript section. Click Run (in jsfiddle), open dev tool  to see the log.